# Checking the Harald Helfgott proof of the little Goldbach conjecture without a public release of numerical checks?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, prime-numbers, conjectures

A few month ago, a proof of the little/ternary Goldbach conjecture has been claimed by Harald Helfgott with three articles:

- [Major arcs for Goldbach's theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2897)
- [Minor arcs for Goldbach's theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5252)
- [Numerical Verification of the Ternary Goldbach Conjecture up to 8.875e30](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3062)

As I understand, the little Goldbach conjecture has been proven analytically in the range $[10^{30}, +\infty]$ and checked numerically in the range $[0, 10^{30}]$. I think that the proof is currently verified by referees, but I wonder how the numerical part is checked without any public release of the code. From an ethical point of view, I would think that any claim of numerical check would require the code to be publicly released. I've searched but I found nothing.

How numerical proofs are checked without access to the source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From an ethical point of view, I would think that any claim of numerical check would require the code to be publicly released.

I think that claim is maybe a bit strong. If there is a description of the algorithm in the literature sufficiently precise for a competent expert to reconstruct the computation, then why insist on the actual source code? (Just to clarify, I totally agree that having code available would be *desirable*; I'm just saying that I disagree with your assertion that it is an *ethical obligation*.)

My cursor is hovering over the button to vote that this question be closed as "primarily opinion-based"...

Comment: It's generally considered to be bad form to vote to close a question after you have posted an answer to it.

Comment: I can remove the opinion-based part. But the question remains: "How numerical proofs are checked without access to the source code ?". For an open problem dated from 1742, just requiring the description of the algorithm does not seem to me as a deep verification. It's like describing a calculation procedure without requiring the actual calculation.

Comment: No, this is not quite true, I think. The paper of Helfgott provides the key things. Maybe, the code is not the most important thing here.

Answer (score 2):

In physics, if you have an extraordinary claim of a result, people do not only want to see the explanation (connection here: the explanation) or the raw-data (the source-code), but they insist to have another **independent** experiment verifing the claims.

I guess the same should be true for numerical results in mathematics: Other groups should code independently the program explained by the paper, and make their findings public.